# jQuery - How do I select an element by ID that has characters?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I working with the following form on a WordPress website:

```
<input id="abc_settings[update_date]" name= "abc_settings[update_date]" 
type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked('1', $abc_options['update_date']); ?>/>
```

If I change the id to "update", I can select it using

```
value = $('#update').val();
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to get the value of `abc_settings[update_date]`. 
This one is not working:

```
value = $('abc_settings[update_date]').val();
```

I keep the name abc_settings so that I can use `global $abc_settings` and `global $abc_options` in WordPress.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to escape the `[` and `]` characters like this:

```
value = $('#abc_settings\\[update_date\\]').val();
```

I'm not entirely sure if that will work, but I'm basing it off of this:

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Comment: Don't forget the hash, ex.: value = $('#abc_settings\\\[update_date\\\]').val();